# add some key to new key in hash use ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash and I want to add new key based on the old key.

```rb
{
  no_errors: ["user1", "user2"],
  invalid_name: ["admin1", "user5"],
  invalidtype: ["user4", "user5"],
  other_errors: ["hello", "world"]
}
```

If `key != no_errors` I need to add new key "all_errors" output:

```rb
{
  no_errors: ["user1", "user2"],
  all_errors: {
    invalid_name: ["admin1", "user5"],
    invalidtype: ["user4", "user5"],
    other_errors: ["hello", "world"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```rb
old_hash = {
  no_errors: ["user1", "user2"],
  invalid_name: ["admin1", "user5"],
  invalidtype: ["user4", "user5"],
  other_errors: ["hello", "world"]
} 
new_hash = {
  no_errors: old_hash.delete(:no_errors),
  all_errors: old_hash
}
```